# JPA Spring boot remove reference on delete?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Im using JPA, MySQL and Spring boot

I cant for the life of me figure out how to apply cascades, the documentation doesnt seem to apply what I intend:

eg.
https://hellokoding.com/deleting-data-with-jpa-hibernate/
Use CascadeType.ALL or CascadeType.REMOVE attributes to delete the child entities when the parent entity is deleted. They may be used on @OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne, and @ManyToMany

^ I don't want to remove child entities I want to ONLY remove reference

my guess is this relationship is many-to-many?

```
many users can have many modules
many modules can have many users
```

How do I get it to apply this via cascade annotation?

```
when a user is deleted the module is not

when a module is deleted its reference is removed from user

when a user is added a module is not

when a module is added a user is not
```

Current entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "module")
public class Module {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "modules")
    private Set<User> users;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `orphanRemoval` if true - remove from db, if false - not remove

For ManyToMany

```java
@ManyToMany
@Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
private Set<User> users;
```

For OneToMany

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<User> users;
```